# How to get the sum of the Calculated measures flag in PowerBI set to 1

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals, daxstudio

I am facing an issue in PowerBI measure as stated below :-

Below is my table with stated columns , times is the calculated measure I created
**Table name :School**

```
StudentID  location    attendancedays  times  Month 

a           Tamilnadu       20           1     Jan
b           Tamilnadu        15          1     Jan
c           Tamilnadu        10          0     Jan
d           Tamilnadu        14          1     Jan 
a1           Delhi           10          0     Jan
b1           Delhi           18          1     Jan 
c1           Delhi           24          1     Feb 
d1           Delhi           21          1     Feb
```

I created a measure to calculate times in PowerBI

```
times= IF(School[attendance]>=12,1,0)
```

**Results Expected /Expected output:**

```
 location      times  Month   
 Tamilnadu     3     Jan
 Delhi         1     Jan
 Delhi         2     Feb
```

It is visualized in the above table as shown but my requirement is to find the sum of the TIMES = 1 per month per location .

How can I achieve it?

Can someone suggest an approach.

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: based the sample data you gave. Can we see your expected output?

Comment: @JonWay I have also added the expected output under Result Expected in above thread

Comment: @JonWay The Student ID should not be displayed in the expected output.Its somewhat like fixed LOD concept we use in Tableau

Answer (score 0):

Create the following measure:

```
measure = CALCULATE(COUNT(School[attendance]), KEEPFILTERS(School[attendance] >= 12))
```